# how install and import OL-Cesium library in angular application

Tags: angular, openlayers, cesiumjs

I am trying to import Ol-Cesium library in our .TS file after install this through NPM,
but we are not able to import this file.

I try this method,

```
npm i --save olcs
import OLCesium from 'olcs/OLCesium.js';
```

After install when we import this file its showing error,
[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTEzl.png)

how to solve this ...

Comment: And did you try doing what is shown in the error message?

Comment: @E.Maggini yes but error not resolve.